# How to pass flag to child serializer in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a nested serializer and I want to pass Parent serializer data to the child. But I don't understand how can I do this. I want to do something like this:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    use_additional_fields = serializers.BooleanField()
    persons = PersonSerializer(many=True)



class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_date_of_birth(self, value):
       if parent.use_additional_fields and not value:
          raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Date of birth is required'))
       return value

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('phone', 'date_of_birth')
```

So if user select `use_additional_fields` in parent serializer, then some of my fields in child serializers should be required

Comment: You can override validate in BookingSerializer and call validation functions from PersonSerializer from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data from request object directly:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_date_of_birth(self, value):
       if self.context['request'].data.get('use_additional_fields') and not value:
          raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Date of birth is required'))
       return value

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('phone', 'date_of_birth')
```

Note if you initiate serializer instance manually in your view, you should pass request to the serializer's [context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context):

```
serializer = BookingSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
```